# Recommendation for Optimum Template Engine for Python Web Dev in a Particular Use Case

Tags: jquery, python, template-engine

For Python Web Development, there is a large selection of template engines. My work is limited to a fairly narrow/specific set of use cases. A description of these might suggest to someone who has a working knowledge with many/most of them, that one of them is better suited for my particular use cases. In other words, there might be one among this group that was optimized against a spec close to my own use case, if so i would like to know what it is.

Here are the criteria that describe those uses cases:

- server-side language is *python*, but i hope that i don't need a lot
  of python expressions in my templates
- i will use it with the python web servers *CherryPy* and (likely)
  *Twisted*
- *jQuery* is is the language in which the data display
  libraries/plug-ins are written
- the templates describe abstract web pages used for *data display*
  (*BI Dashboard*, is a fair description) once the server delivers the data to the
  template (in response to form selections submitted on an antecedent
  page) i just want to display the data in a *grid*, e.g., the jQuery
  plug-in jqgrid, or in a plot, e.g., one of the standard types in
  *Flot*
- *performance* is critical, but the scope is very narrow--only for a
  data handling and rendering--i expect grids will often be populated
  with several thousand data rows (though the grid itself will be
  paginated); likewise, the plots could easily have a thousand or so
  data points, though again, the pre-processing and computation will be
  done elsewhere
- very little need for a rich syntax (no need for complex multi-way
  branching, etc.)--i prefer to do any processiong/computation on the
  server (and again, data filtering will almost always be done by the
  jQuery plugin i use to render the data)
- likewise, the user's interaction with the displayed data is through
  native elements supplied by the jQuery plug-in (e.g., page up/down,
  sort, etc.)
- a "designer-friendly" template is not really important (not because i
  don't like designers, but because the design effort required should
  be low enough so that i even i can do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your templating requirements are really simple, then I suggest you to use [Python's builtin String Formatting engine](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#string-formatting)...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). It offers precompilation of templates, allows familiar Python syntax and is framework-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

[Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) and the [Django template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/#the-template-layer) engine all do this.  For that matter, anything on this list will work, also: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

None of the requirements is particularly interesting.   They don't point to any product because they're very general.

Except this, which doesn't belong.

> likewise, the user's interaction with the displayed data is through native elements supplied by the jQuery plug-in (e.g., page up/down, sort, etc.)

This is irrelevant.  No user  can ever interact with the template.  They interact with a web page that provides data to the template.